# R: Create a matrix with randomly generated number of cells with values in each rows and randomly generated values of each of those cells

Tags: r

For example, to simulate 10,000 values where claims have a compound
Poisson distribution with parameter 1000 and a gamma claims distribution with 750 and 0.25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like :

```
sapply(rpois(10000,1000), function(n){sum(rgamma(n,shape = 750, scale = 0.25))})
```

I am not sure about your parametrisation of the gamma r.v.s there is also the `rate` parameter if you need.

Although I'm not sure, this looks a lot like what a teacher would ask ;)

Edit : a list of individual claims can be obtained by :

```
sapply(rpois(10000,1000), function(n){rgamma(n,shape = 750, scale = 0.25)})
```

Comment: Hey the issue is that the number of individual claims is not the same each time (it's a poisson). So the only solution is to show them as a list, just removing the `sum()` from my line. If you are hapy with my ansewr, please accept it (there is a button on the left of my answer).